# Ruby linkify for urls in strings

Tags: ruby, regex, linkify

There have been a few posts about linkifying text using a regex. The most popular [is this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758135/c-code-to-linkify-urls-in-a-string).

However my spec is a little more tricky:

```
describe TextFormatter do 

  def l(input) 
    TextFormatter.gsub_links!(input){|link| "!!#{link}!!"}
  end

  it "should detect simple links" do
    l("http://www.cnn.com").should == "!!http://www.cnn.com!!"
  end

  it "should detect multi links" do
    l("http://www.cnn.com http://boats.com?help.asp").should == "!!http://www.cnn.com!! !!http://boats.com?help.asp!!"
  end

  it "should compensate for parans properly" do 
    l("(http://this.is?hello_world)").should == "(!!http://this.is?hello_world!!)"
  end

  it "should ignore existing links" do 
    s = "<A HREF='http://sam.com'> http://sam.com </A>"
    l(s.dup).should == s
  end

  it "should allow parans" do 
    l("http://sam.com.au?(red)").should == "!!http://sam.com.au?(red)!!"
  end

end
```

Any ideas how to implement the hairy Regex:

This is where I am so far (it fails 2 tests):

```
  def gsub_links!(input)
    regex = /https?\:\/\/[\-\w+&@#\/%?=~\(\)\|!:,.;]*[\-\w+&@#\/%=~_\(\)|]/
    input.gsub!(regex) { |link|
      yield link
    }
  end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I might be missing some context, but why re-invent the wheel?  Have you tried `auto_link` in `actionpack`?

```
$ gem install actionpack

$ irb -f --prompt simple
>> require 'action_view'
>> include ActionView::Helpers

>> auto_link("abc http://google.com xyz")
=> "abc <a href=\"http://google.com\">http://google.com</a> xyz"
>> auto_link("abc <a href='http://google.com'>google</a> xyz")
=> "abc <a href='http://google.com'>google</a> xyz"
```

Comment: yerp, auto link seems to pass all my tests ... thanks for pointing it out

Comment: why it might not work in app? I'm getting an error "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) file: tag_helper.rb location: tag_options line: 113" while trying to do that. It works perfectly in console though

Comment: `auto_link` is gone from Rails since 3.1. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418710/replacing-the-auto-link-method-in-ruby-on-rails-3-1 for an updated answer.