# Replacing the 'auto_link' method in Ruby on Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, replace

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I know that in the 3.1 version there won't be the `auto_link` method anymore (see the [actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.0.rc4/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb) for RoR 3.1).

**Is there another way to have similar functions as the old `auto_link` method? That is, how can I replace that useful method in Ruby on Rails 3.1?**

*BTW*: why will the `auto_link` method will be removed?

Comment: Some reasons for its removal can be found on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732216/why-was-auto-link-deprecated-in-rails

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[**Rinku**](https://github.com/vmg/rinku) is a drop-in replacement for Rails 3.1 `auto_link`.

Auto-linking functionality has been removed from Rails 3.1, *and is instead offered as a standalone gem,* [**rails_autolink**](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink). You can choose to use Rinku instead.

```
require 'rails_rinku'
```

The rails_rinku package monkeypatches Rails with an `auto_link` method that mimics 100% the original one, parameter per parameter. It's just faster.

Comment: Wouldn't recommend rinku right now.  For example, this causes a segfault: Rinku.auto_link('<')

Comment: Just add this to your Gemfile:

    `gem 'rinku', '~> 1.2.2', :require => 'rails_rinku'`

Comment: Rinku.auto_link('<') still segfaults

Comment: @James not anymore (as of 1.5.0)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but Aaron Patterson (Rails Core team) seem to have the gem for this as well https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink (which worked fine for me, YMMV)