# How do I stop auto_link from escaping angle brackets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, escaping

I would like for my app to allow users to post links in their posts, and for those links to automatically be recognized. To do so, I have been using auto_link as such: the following is the partial that is called to show a person's post:

_post.html.erb:

```
 <tr>
     <td >
    <span class="post_header"><h4><%= link_to "#{post.user.first_name} #{post.user.last_name}", post.user %></h4></span>
    <p> <%= auto_link(post.content) %> </p>
    <span class="post_timestamp">
        Opined <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago
    </span>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

this outputs the following, for a single post.content:

```
 <p> Wondering if this link &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.economist.com/blogs/freeexchange&quot;&gt;http://www.economist.com/blogs/freeexchange&lt;/a&gt; will become a proper link
```

Why does auto-link create/escape the angle brackets to <a etc? Is there some way to fix this, as this does not create working links. Instead the output in the browser is:

```
 Wondering if this link <a href="http://www.economist.com/blogs/freeexchange">http://www.economist.com/blogs/freeexchange</a> will become a proper link
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rails 3, erb will default to not allow any ruby output to contain html. To get around this you can use `"some string".html_safe`

```
<%= auto_link(post.content).html_safe %>
```

But of course any html or javascript will then be allowed. So...

```
<%= sanitize(auto_link(post.content).html_safe) %>
```

Comment: amazing! spent so long with no idea how to fix this.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that auto_link was removed with Rails 3.1.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418710/replacing-the-auto-link-method-in-ruby-on-rails-3-1) for replacement solutions.

Answer (score 0):

tybro0103's solution works, but if you want ONLY links as proper HTML, you'll need

```
sanitize(auto_link(post.content).html_safe,tags:'a')
```