# error when using rinku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autolink

How can I get rinku to run and the page to load properly?

Error message: `uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Rinku`

Steps taken:

- Installed `rinku gem` and `rake-compiler` and ran `$ rake` per the gem
  developer's instructions
- Inserted `require 'rinku'` into the controller file
- Inserted the following into the view file `<% text = "Go to http://www.abc.com or email me at dude@abc.com" %>` and `<%= Rinku.auto_link(text, mode=:all, link_attr=nil, skip_tags=nil) %>`

Comment: Your have a version of Rails > 3.1?

Comment: Hi Sparda - I have 3.2.13

Answer (score 2):

The correct installation of Rinku in a Rails 3.2 app is:

1. Add `gem 'rinku'` to your Gemfile.
2. `bundle install`
3. Restart your Rails server, if it was already running.

Don't add `require 'rinku'` or bother with `rake` or the `rake-compiler`.

The `Rinku.auto_link(text)` should now work in your view. If the HTML renders as plain text, you may need to add `raw` or `html_safe` e.g.

`<%= raw Rinku.auto_link(text) %>`
or
`<%= Rinku.auto_link(text).html_safe %>`

Versions: rails 3.2.13, rinku 1.7.3

Answer (score 1):

`auto_link` has been removed from Rails after version 3. [Replacement gems are available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418710/replacing-the-auto-link-method-in-ruby-on-rails-3-1/6418813#6418813).

Comment: Thanks Mori.  Yeah, I saw that one.  Is there a way to do it with the "rails_autolink" standalone gem instead of "rails_rinku"?  Looks like there are some segfaults issues