# How to Linkify Phone numbers in IE using C# BHO

Tags: c#, .net, bho

I'm able to detect phone numbers from webpage but unable to linkify them. I want to to linkify a phone no. like 7774443333 to [7774443333](http://mysite.com/call=7774443333)

Is there any way to do that? 
Is their any solution, Is their any method to wrap anchor element around any word in the webpage or something better solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758135/c-code-to-linkify-urls-in-a-string does this help?

Comment: I tried...its good when you want to replace string to webpage...i want to replace webpage to webpage... when I use tempElement.innerHTML = Regex.Replace(tempElement.innerHTML, @"[0-9]{10}", "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>"); ...then it also replaces the <div id="9998886666"> like or some other hidden things to visible links... I just want to linkify visible text on webpage

Answer (score 0):

If your putting this on a webform, you could put the text in a label, and wrap the label in an a href, then change the navigation url on the a href in code-behind.

Comment: Actually I'm putting this application on client machine, just like skype extension for IE

Comment: any solution for webbrowser control??

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a perfect example of IMarkupServices::InsertElement