# Regular expression to find URLs within a string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# code to linkify urls in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758135/c-code-to-linkify-urls-in-a-string)

I'm sure this is a stupid question but I can't find a decent answer anywhere. I need a good URL regular expression for C#. It needs to find all URLs in a string so that I can wrap each one in html to make it clickable.

1. What is the best expression to use for this?
2. Once I have the expression, what is the best way to replace these URLs with their properly formatted counterparts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate? [C# Code to Linkify URLs in a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758135/c-code-to-linkify-urls-in-a-string)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I am using this right now:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text,
                @"((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)",
                "<a target='_blank' href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

Comment: Did you use this code exactly? Visual Studio thinks that all of those backslashes are "Unrecognized escape sequence"s.

Comment: @brainmurphy1 Did you include the `@` in front of the opening quote for the string? That tells the parser/compiler that it is a string literal and to ignore escape sequences.

Comment: Yes, thank you; I figured that out. It works as it should.

Comment: be wary of tabnabbing - best to also add "rel noopener noreferrer" to any links with a target of '_blank' - see https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/256-targetblank---the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever/

Answer (score 11):

Use this code

```
protected string MakeLink(string txt)
{
     Regex regx = new Regex("http://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);        
     MatchCollection mactches = regx.Matches(txt);        
     foreach (Match match in mactches)
     {
         txt = txt.Replace(match.Value, "<a href='" + match.Value + "'>" + match.Value + "</a>");
     }    
     return txt;
}
```

Comment: Use the `{}` button, not the `"` button. :)

Comment: Use `RegexOptions.Compiled` and `String.Format`

Comment: Also, have a look at [@ quoted string expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(v=VS.100).aspx#CodeSnippetContainerCode6) It makes your regex a lot more readable (not to mention being able to copy/paste and whatnot). ie. `"@http://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&amp;\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?"`

Comment: Slight tweak to great suggestion from @RichardMarskell-Drackir.  The @ sign is prepended ahead of the opening double quote for the string.  So it's `@"http://([\......."`   rather than `"@http://([\......."`

Comment: This will fail for HTTPS sites.