# Regex replace urls with tag

Tags: c#, html, regex

In html need replace url to tag

Only http://google3.com:1139 and http://google6.com:1139

```html
<div>
  <a href="http://google1.com:1139" target="_blank">http://google2.com:1139</a> 
  http://google3.com:1139
</div>
<div>
  <a href="http://google4.com:1139" target="_blank">http://google5.com:1139</a>
  http://google6.com:1139
</div>
```

Must be

```html
<div>
  <a href="http://google1.com:1139" target="_blank">http://google2.com:1139</a> 
  <a href="http://google3.com:1139" target="_blank">http://google3.com:1139</a> 
</div>
<div>
  <a href="http://google4.com:1139" target="_blank">http://google5.com:1139</a>
  <a href="http://google6.com:1139" target="_blank">http://google6.com:1139</a> 
</div>
```

[I found solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750015/regular-expression-to-find-urls-within-a-string)

```c#
        var result = Regex.Replace("<div><a href=\"http://google1.com:1139\" target=\"_blank\">http://google2.com:1139</a>http://google3.com:1139</div><div><a href=\"http://google4.com:1139\" target=\"_blank\">http://google5.com:1139</a>http://google6.com:1139</div>", 
                                   @"((?<!href=['""]?)(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)",
                                   "<a target='_blank' href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

But need replace

1. started with **http** but now with **href="http** (found)
2. not ended with

```html
</a>
```

3. or skip between

```html
<a ... </a>
```

Comment: Maybe you need simpler expression? [Like This](https://regex101.com/r/f1fbC5/1)

Comment: @CommonSense May be. I need replace http://google3.com:1139 and http://google6.com:1139 to template <a target='_blank' href='$1'>$1</a>

Comment: If it is only these two, why not simply use `string.replace("http://google3.com:1139","<a href='http://google3.com:1139' target='_blank'>http://google3.com:1139</a>");`? And same for google6...

Comment: If it only shall be done when it occurs as child of <div> better use XML parsing and XPath than Regex.

Comment: @Fildor Can be more two and any urls

Comment: After edit: I'd use XPath to get all Text-Children of divs, then check the Text Value if it matches your urls and if so replace the textnode with a new anchor node accordingly. Maybe have a look into **Linq to XML**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it the requirements may be rephrased as follows:

- everything between `<a` and `</a>` should be left intact (this includes `href` attribute values)
- any URLs of the given pattern outside the `<a` and `</a>` should be wrapped in anchor tags.

This may be achieved by searching two patterns, `<a.*?</a>` and <some URL>, as alternatives. Then replace the match by itself if the first pattern is found and by a wrapped URL if the second pattern found:

```
Regex.Replace(html,
    @"<a.*?</a>|(?:https?|ftp)://[\w_.-]+:\d+",
    m => m.Value.StartsWith("<") 
        ? m.Value
        : string.Format("<a target='_blank' href='{0}'>{0}</a>", m.Value));
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/Jq1s8y

P.S.

I simplified the URL regex for the sake of conciseness. The real application may require more extended pattern.