# URL regex - not getting it to work

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am using the following regex to find if there is a url present in a text, however it seems to miss some URLs like:

- `youtube.be/8P0BxJO`
- `youtube.com/watch?v=VrmlFL`

and also some bit.ly links (but not all)

```
Match m = Regex.Match(nc[i].InnerText, 
   @"(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/\S\w[\w- ;,./?%&=]\S*)?");

if (m.Success)
{
    MessageBox.Show(nc[i].InnerText);
}
```

any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Your regex returns true for your examples; your issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: Perhaps you can supply us with more details about your code and the text you are trying to parse.

Comment: As other comments suggest, both URLs work with the current expression, as tested with this little handy tool over at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Your regex works for me, but I think you are missing a backslash before "?"

Comment: [\w- ;,./?%&=] should probably be [\w- ;,./\?%&=]

Comment: @Ondra - ? isn't a special character inside a character class.

Comment: It matches fine as it is. Though, it also matches `bad.so` in the sentence `this is bad.so not good` :)

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758135/c-sharp-code-to-linkify-urls-in-a-string) related question, the first answer should help you out.  The suggestion both finds links and then replaces them, so obviously just take what you need.  [This](http://snipplr.com/view/13286/) and [this](http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/C-Sharp/C-Code-Snippet-Extract-URLs.html) article are different approaches that should get you more or less the same result.

Another (perhaps more reliable) non-regex approach would be to tokenize the string by splitting on spaces and punctuation, and then checking the tokens to see whether they are a valid uri using [Uri.IsWellFormedUriString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx) (which only works on well formed uri's, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835269/how-to-check-that-a-uri-string-is-valid) question points out).